# querying data from DynamoDB using python

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query records from Dynamodb by only using the partition key which is "name" and also want to filter based on code here is an example of a dictionary stored in Dynamodb

```html
{
  "name": {
    "S": "jeettest"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "103"
  },
  "subject": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "date": {
            "S": "2015-10-22"
          },
          "id": {
            "S": "1"
          },
          "subject_name": {
            "S": "maths"
          },
          "code": {
            "S": "610"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "date": {
            "S": "2016-10-22"
          },
          "id": {
            "S": "2"
          },
          "subject_name": {
            "S": "science"
          },
          "code": {
            "S": "100"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


{
  "name": {
    "S": "test"
  },
  "id": {
    "S": "104"
  },
  "subject": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "date": {
            "S": "2018-10-22"
          },
          "id": {
            "S": "1"
          },
          "subject_name": {
            "S": "maths"
          },
          "code": {
            "S": "610"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "date": {
            "S": "2017-10-22"
          },
          "id": {
            "S": "4"
          },
          "subject_name": {
            "S": "history"
          },
          "code": {
            "S": "400"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

how can we filter based on name and subject_code

from the above code, I was able to get the list of records by partition key but I also want to get only records that have code = 400 as we can see above we have two Json one has code = 400 and another Json does not have so want to filter that out.

Comment: Also, is it possible to update the list of dict which has subject code  = '400' and add two more key-value pair where we find the subject code  = '400'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result=table.query(
            IndexName='name',
            KeyConditionExpression='name=:name',
            FilterExpression: 'contains(code, :code)',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':name':'ABC',
                ':code': '400'
            })['Items']
```